# PHP - Error 404 after choose dropdown list

Tags: codeigniter, fuelcms

[404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC0TJ.png)

I got this error when choose data from dropdown list. Below is my .htaccess file
I have go through my codes but did not find what's wrong. Can anyone help me how to debug in php? I am using Wamp server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Allow asset folders through
RewriteRule ^(fuel/modules/(.+)?/assets/(.+)) - [L]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(fuel/install/.+|fuel/crons/.+|fuel/data_backup/.+|fuel/codeigniter/.+|fuel/modules/.+|fuel/application/.+|\.git.+) - [F,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Did you set the base_url ? what is fuel in your URL ? is this the directory inside your controller directory ??

Comment: @CaPsLoCk This is my base url `$base_url = 'http://localhost/';`